# Best route to take for dynamically updating a picklist field based on anothe picklist field triggered by a checkbox?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, dynamic-picklist

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction as to how to assign a picklist value (Product) that corresponds to another picklist value (Location), specific when a checkbox is checked (New Box).

The values from Product will correspond to Location based on a list (i.e., Product1 > Chicago, Product2 > San Fransisco, etc...).  So when the checkbox is checked, only then will the Location update based on the Product selection picklist.

I hope that makes sense, I just don't know which direction to take (i.e., flow, formula, etc...).  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps -

1. Create metadata which will have two fields city and the product.
2. You can use trigger/flow where you will create a map which will have the key as a city and value as a product.
3. If the checkbox is checked you just need to get the product from the map using the city and assign it to the picklist.
4. Perform the DML, and ignore the DML if it's in before inserting/updating.